# Visual Prolog error c502: The expression does not produce a value

Tags: prolog, visual-prolog, turbo-prolog

I am trying to translate a simple Turbo Prolog problem to Visual Prolog 7.1

The original Turbo Prolog code is the following.

```
    DOMAINS
            s=string   sl=s*  sll=sl*

    PREDICATES
            select(sl,s,sl)
            solve(sll)

    CLAUSES

            select([A|B],A,B).
            select([A|B],C,[A|D]):- select(B,C,D).

            solve([["Anna",A,A],["Kate",Vp,Vt],                ["Natasha",Np,"green"]]):-
                    select(["white","green","blue"],A,ColPl),
                    select(["white","blue"],A,[Vt]), Vt<>"white",
                    select(ColPl,Vp,[Np]), Vp<>"white", Np<>"green".
```

And its resulting list is outputted with `solve(Out)` with provides a correct result to the Turbo Prolog console.

When trying to translate this to Visual Prolog, I get error c502 in line 33.

```
    implement main
        open core

    constants
        className = "main".
        classVersion = "".
    domains
    s=string.
    sl=s*.
    sll=sl*.
    %
    class predicates
    select:(sl,s,sl) nondeterm anyflow.
    solve:(sll) nondeterm anyflow.
    %
    clauses
    %
    select([A|B],A,B).
    select([A|B],C,[A|D]):- select(B,C,D).
    %
    solve([["Anna",A,A],["Kate",Vp,Vt],["Natasha",Np,"green"]]):-
    select(["white","green","blue"],A,ColPl),
    select(["white","blue"],A,[Vt]), Vt<>"white",
    select(ColPl,Vp,[Np]), Vp<>"white", Np<>"green".

    clauses
        classInfo(className, classVersion).

    clauses
        run():-
            console::init(),
            %ERROR AFTER THIS LINE
            stdIO::writef("%", solve(Out)),fail().

    end implement main

    goal
        mainExe::run(main::run).
```

What I get from this error is that `solve(Out)` does not give anything to print. What I do not know is how to change the code to produce something to print.

I am a beginner in Prolog and I cannot figure out how to fix this problem and Google is not much of a help either, this seems to be very obscure problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Visual Prolog, but could you rewrite the offending line as:

```
solve(Out), stdIO::writef("%", Out),fail().
```

and try again?

Remember that predicates are not functions like in other programming languages; they do not have a return value.

**EDIT to answer comment**: a procedure predicate should succeed exactly one time. Here, `main` is calling your `solve` function which my fail or succeeds several time. To ensure that, you can try to wrap the call to solve into another predicate:

```
wrap_solve(S) :- solve(S), !.
wrap_solve([]).
```

The cut after the call to `solve` should ensure that you get only one solution if it succeeds.
If there's no solution (i.e., the call to `solve` fails), then the second clause will give a default value (an empty list in that case).

In `main`, you should call `wrap_solve` instead of `solve`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and correction to my understanding of predicates!
Unfortunately this change creates another error:

error c631: The predicate 'main::run/0', which is declared as 'procedure', is actually 'failure'

Comment: Might be because of the `fail()` in your definition of `main`.

Comment: With this change the 'failure' is now replaced with 'nondeterm'

Comment: Thank you!
In addition of your changes, I had to declare the predicate in `class predicates` with this code `wrap_solve:(sll) procedure (o).`